# Is there a common word for floor and ceiling?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, common-word

Walls divide rooms but what do you call what divides stories?

Looking from below it would be the *ceiling*, looking from above it would be the *floor*. But when looking at it from the outside? Is there a common word?

I am looking for a word which describes structures that divide a space vertically as opposed to *walls* which divide the space horizontally.

Comment: The problem with asking for a neutral term between ceiling and floor is that they aren't always two sides of the same coin. Especially in multi-story buildings, there's often a space between the ceiling and the floor above (cf. interstitial space). Of the two, the floor is definitely the more important and the better built--he floor has to be safe to walk on, while the ceiling is just there to conceal whatever is above (and under the floor)--so perhaps the answer below that suggests floor is the best for your purposes.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, "plane" would be the word, but I don't know if that's too abstract for what you need.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Believe it or not, the word you are looking for is floor.

It refers to **both** the space between and the actual divisions. But the space between can have other names like story ("storey" in British English).

If it were a house it would be the *roof*.

I think you could use *"floor slab"* or deck.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. http://www.energyefficientbuild.com/images/foundation-anatomy.gif

Answer (score 4):

The actual word for a vertical partition between two stories is called a **Party Structure**.

Wanted to create a different answer because my other answer was related but different.

- NOTE: This word is used more in the UK than it is in the US.

> Party Structure Diagram

[image: Vertical Partition]

Comment: @RomanReiner Hopefully this helps

Comment: Party structure also covers walls, fence walls etc.

Comment: A party structure divides separate apartments--be they vertical or horizontal. And a detached single family home wouldn't have any party structures.

Comment: this just sounds like a british-ism for "partition" to me

Comment: @sgroves have you tried [googling 'partition'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=partition+in+house&safe=off&es_sm=119&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=CsHyU5XIFM2Y1AWymIBY&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1436&bih=805)?

Comment: [Note that party structure may have other uses.](http://www.dpdcoaching.co.uk/sports-coaching-sussex-images/Bouncy%20Castle%20picture.jpg)

Comment: @OllieFord i know what partition means. ermanen said *party structure* also covers walls, fence walls, etc. so it sounds like a (very british) synonym for "partition" to me. maybe that's not the case, but that's what it seems like from the comments here.

Comment: @sgroves My point was that if you follow my link above, you will see only walls; not floor/ceilings.

Comment: @OllieFord that's nice. regardless of what a google image search returns, partition does not strictly mean a vertical structure such as a wall. a floor is a partition too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the word *Partition*. It is even more general and doesn't specify vertically or horizontally. It defines an object which separates something into parts.

So: For a building, a partition separates the building into floors, stories, rooms, or whatever your preference is. As TheFreeDictionary.com says,

> [partition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/partition): a division into parts; separation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I need a word which specifically describes *vertical* partitioning because I have both vertical and horizontal walls/partitions and need to distinguish between them preferably without using the words horizontally and vertically all the time.

Comment: @RomanReiner Can it be a word to describe a vertical partition of something other than walls/a building? Like a word that describes a vertical partitioning of something else but you could redefine the word to others as that?

Comment: It doesn't need to be walls/building specifically I just thought that would be a good image. The important things are that the word describes the structure *dividing* the space and not the divisions themselves and that there are separate words for horizontal and vertical walls.

Comment: when i hear "partition" in regards to a building, i immediately think vertical.

Comment: I agree with @sgroves - but not only vertical, I think not-original (if house is older than a couple decades) and not-solid. 'Partition' is used for vertical.. partitions made from wood and plasterboard, the superset (IMO) 'wall' includes those made from masonry.

Answer (score 1):

A common English term is *stories:*

"This building is seven stories tall."

**EDIT#1**

and alternative is *floor:*

"All the bedrooms are on the fourth floor."

See  [3-A](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/floor)

Comment: A story would be the space between two [word I am looking for]s. [Word I am looking for] would be the structure between two stories.

Comment: @RomanReiner See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score -1):

How about *layer*? Or *dividing layer* Or *separating layer* —  something like that?

*Stratum* is related to layer, but I think *layer* is less scientific sounding.

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be what you're looking for:
Definition from WhatIs.com
searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/definition/plenum

In building construction, a **plenum** (pronounced PLEH-nuhm, from Latin meaning full) is a separate space provided for air circulation for heating, ventilation, and air-conditioning (sometimes referred to as HVAC) and typically provided in the space between the structural ceiling and a drop-down ceiling, or between floors.

Comment: but the word you suggests refers to the space and not to the division which the question asks for.

Comment: Plenum is not a hypernym for floor and ceiling.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at Wiki, for architectural use, the phrase you're looking for is "
"Interstitial space".

Comment: I think this is usually used for the space between floors where things like pipework or other machinery goes. At any rate [that's what Wikipedia seems to think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstitial_space_(architecture))